# How would I get a filtered result from 2 joined tables in a model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, model

I have 2 tables in SQL linked with a foreign key. I want to get the result of this join filtered (where) on a value in the child table into the model in ASP.NET Core MVC. How would I do this.

I have these 2 tables in SQL with the foreign key. I did a database first. So, I have the models in my project.

Also, I created interfaces to these models.

Let's say, table 1 is Order and table 2 is OrderLine.
On a SQL level I would do something like:

```
SELECT 
  Order.CustomerName
  , OrderLine.Product 
FROM Order 
JOIN OrderLine 
  ON Order.OrderID = OrderLine.OrderID 
WHERE OrderLine.NotYetDelivered = True
```

Thus, I want to see a list of customers with the products that they ordered but that they didn't receive yet.

How would I do this in ASP.NET Core with MVC?

I tried a lot with Linq. and had the following piece of code:

```
var classification = classificationRepository.getAllClassifications();
var classificationLanguage = classificationLanguageRepository.getAllClassificationLanguages();

var ClassificationOne1Language = (from c in classification
                                         join l in classificationLanguage
                                           on c.SuClassificationId equals l.SuClassificationId
                                         //where l.SuLanguageId == 1
                                         select new { c.SuClassificationId, l.SuClassificationName });
        //var ClassificationOne1Language = (from c in classificationLanguage
        //                                 select new { c.SuClassificationId, c.SuClassificationName });

        List<ClassificationWithLanguageViewModel> x = new List<ClassificationWithLanguageViewModel>();
        foreach (var c in ClassificationOne1Language)
```

It says on the "foreach" loop the following:
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: 'Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.'

But when I use SQL profiler I get the following SQL and that has 2 rows of result.

```
SELECT [s].[SuClassificationID], [s].[SuClassificationColor], [s].[SuClassificationStatusID], [s].[SuCreateDate], [s].[SuCreatorID], [s].[SuDefaultClassficiationPageID], [s].[SuDropDownSequence], [s].[SuHasDropDown], [s].[SuModifierID], [s].[SuModifyDate]
FROM [SuClassification] AS [s]
```

Any suggestions why on a SQL level I have results but the code thinks different?

Comment: I'd suggest looking into entity framework core. Then you can use Linq queries in your SQL code to query the tables and assign values to your model.

Comment: Just to be clear, there are a number of different ways to do what you're asking. You should probably just google "asp.net retrieve data from database", find something that looks like what you need and have a go, then ask questions if you run into problems.

Comment: Thanks. I did try something like that (i tried many things). If i create a viewmodel and populate this based on a linq query. Would that be a way to go?

Comment: Just for your info.it is actually not about orders but it is easier to explain that way. I am volunteering to build a platform for communities to share knowledge on sustainability.

Comment: Yes, that would work fine.

Comment: Hi Ben, i tried that and have the feeling i slowly get there. Still i have some issues. Added that in the explanation above. Also, i have the feeling it could be written in a more proper coding

Answer (score 1):

if your get result from multiple table and make one entity then below code helps you.

your requirement is to execute query with join and get result.

first create model that related to your return result from your query. for example

```
public class Result
{
     public string CustomerName { get; set; }
     public string Product { get; set; }
}
```

now bind this model to your query in your `DbContext` `OnModelCreating()` method

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
      modelBuilder.Query<Result>();
}
```

now you can access and execute your query with join using custom model.

```
 var query = @"SELECT 
                     Order.CustomerName, 
                     OrderLine.Product 
               FROM Order 
               JOIN OrderLine 
               ON Order.OrderID = OrderLine.OrderID 
               WHERE OrderLine.NotYetDelivered = True";
 var results = _dbContext.Query<Result>().FromSql(query).ToList();
```

also you can pass parameter like below

```
var idParam= new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@id", id);
var results = _dbContext.Query<Result>().FromSql(query,idParam).ToList();
```

and use `@id` as parameter in your query.

in this way you can access or set your custom model and execute query in entity framework core.

if you access using Linq then,]

```
var orderLines = _context.OrderLines.Include(x => x.Order)
                         .Where(ol => ol.NotYetDelivered)
                         .Select(ol => new
                         {
                               CustomerName = ol.Order.CustomerName,
                               Product = ol.Product
                         }).ToList();
```

Here `Include` method to specify related data to be included in query results.

Let me know require more information.

Comment: Hi Lalji, I will give that a try. Will take me a little though. Was struggling with Linq.

Comment: @PeterleGrand just make query model as your query result other things are same or you can execute store procedure that return select same way as execute sql query

Comment: Didn't understand the last comment. What do you mean by Query model? I like your idea on doing it in regular SQL as I am more familiar with that. What is the reason that I only see people doing Linq? Is that because you keep it independent from the database system? or any other reason? I want to do this project with the right techonologies, so if there is any reason not to do it with SQL as you suggested, I will continue learning. But if your idea with regular SQL is as good I might first do that as I feel more familiar with SQL than with Linq.

Comment: @PeterleGrand Query model? means `Result` that return your query result. see doing with linq is easy as simple query but if your query is complex with group by and other many operation than using linq is might be complex so using this way you can execute your query and get your result in your `result` model

Comment: looking into your idea. Most of it I understand. one (probably stupid as I am a beginner) question. I see in your code (and also at other places) and underscore _dbContext what is that about? Also, If I write that line, it doesn't like it (name does not exist in this current context). I have tried various things here but run then into other issues (like declaring an dbcontext variable). Any suggestion?

Comment: @PeterleGrand _dbContext is your instance of `DbContext` means as per your code your method `classificationRepository.getAllClassifications();` if you are using ef core then your repository might be used `DbContext`, which can be used to query and save instances of your entities to a database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ToList()` if you would like to return a list of entity.Refer to my demo which uses dbcontext bu DI and linq query

1.ClassificationWithLanguageViewModel.cs

```
public class ClassificationWithLanguageViewModel
{
    public int SuClassificationId { get; set; }
    public string SuClassificationName { get; set; }
}
```

2.DbContext:

```
public DbSet<Classification> Classification { get; set; }
public DbSet<ClassificationLanguage> ClassificationLanguage { get; set; }
```

2.Action:

```
List<ClassificationWithLanguageViewModel> classificationOne1Language = 
                                          await (from c in _context.Classification
                                          join l in _context.ClassificationLanguage
                                          on c.SuClassificationId equals l.SuClassificationId
                                          select new ClassificationWithLanguageViewModel 
                                          { 
                                            SuClassificationId = c.SuClassificationId,
                                            SuClassificationName =  l.SuClassificationName 
                                          }).ToListAsync();

foreach (var c in classificationOne1Language)
{

}
```

Comment: Hi @XingZou, I tried, now I get a Null error on the line of List<ClassificationWithLanguageViewModel>. But when I check in the SQL profiler it shows a SQL statement that is correct and when running that statement in SQL studio I get 2 records back. So, how can it be that the Linq line gets a Null error while SQL returns records. Can it have to do with the ToList? In the other solution they suggested ToListAsync and await _context. I can imagine that that would wait for the result. But I don't know how to place await _context. into your Linq script. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Peter le Grand Both of async and sync could retrieve the data. What are the `classification` and `classificationLanguage`?  Refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause)

Comment: The classification and  classificationlanguage are a very small part of the thing I am building. the idea is that content will be created in the platform. This content (richtext articles) can then be linked to classifications (e.g. is it about climate, polution, etc..) But this must need to support multi language depending on the user. So if the user is Spanish, then the word "Climate" will show in Spanish. I will have a look at your link. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague. You stated that you essentially want the following SQL query as LINQ. That's actually very straight forward:

```
SELECT 
  Order.CustomerName
, OrderLine.Product 
FROM Order 
JOIN OrderLine 
  ON Order.OrderID = OrderLine.OrderID 
WHERE OrderLine.NotYetDelivered = True
```

Translates to:

```
var orders = await _context.Orders
    .Where(o => o.OrderLines.Any(ol => ol.NotYetDelivered))
    .Select(o => new
    {
        CustomerName = o.CustomerName,
        Products = o.OrderLines.Select(ol => ol.Product)
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

However, I have a sneaking suspicion that what you *actually* want is only order lines that have not been delivered. The above query and LINQ will actually give you *orders* that simply have one or more order lines that haven't been delivered, but it will still include *all* related order lines, whether they've been delivered or not. If you just want undelivered order lines, then you should start by querying the order lines:

```
var orderLines = await _context.OrderLines
    .Where(ol => ol.NotYetDelivered)
    .Select(ol => new
    {
        CustomerName = ol.Order.CustomerName,
        Product = ol.Product
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Hi Chris, this syntax looks somehow different. One thing though I am especially interested in is the .ToListAsync. I was trying ToList. With the rewritten Linq query as suggested in the answer below. But then the result is Null. While if I check in SQL profiler, it shows a SQL query based on the Linq query that works. Can this be related to this Async with await_context that I didn't use?